# ReferenceError: ReadableStream is not defined while running jest tests

Tags: testing, redux, jestjs, redux-saga, jsdom

My web app reads local files using a custom ReadableStream (in-order that I won't need to have a max file size that the platform supports) and it works great, both for correctly formatted files and error files. My app is built using React-Redux-Saga.

I'm now attempting to add limited `e2e` tests to my code to test the state management. I'm testing that when sending `redux` actions the state updates correctly. I'm testing the saga's using the package `redux-saga-tester`.

While running the jest client tests that read local files using the ReadableStream I built, I got an error `ReferenceError: ReadableStream is not defined`. What I understood is that the `jsdom` environment that `jest` uses is missing the ReadableStream implementation. I than added the `web-streams-polyfill` package to polyfill the ReadableStream class.

Now the validate file test is passing as in the browser:

```
test('Select and validate log file', async () => {
  const testFile = testFileBuilder.valid();
  storeTester.dispatch(fileSelected(testFile));
  await storeTester.waitFor(FILE_VALIDATED);
  const state = storeTester.getState().file;
  expect(state.fileValidated).toBeTruthy();
});
```

My problem is that when I run a second validation test with an invalid file the test passes but prints an error to the console.

The test:

```
test('Select an invalid file - JSON error', async () => {
    const testFile = testFileBuilder.errorJSON();
    storeTester.dispatch(fileSelected(testFile));
    await storeTester.waitFor(FILE_ERROR);
    const state = storeTester.getState().file;
    expect(state.fileValidated).toBeFalsy();
    expect(state.fileError).toBeTruthy();
  });
```

The error that is printed after the test completes successfully:

```
e.error node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/virtual-console.js:29
    Error: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:80
        at Object.dispatchError (/home/noams/dev/web/visual-log-viewer/client/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/xhr-utils.js:65:19)
        at Request.client.on.err (/home/noams/dev/web/visual-log-viewer/client/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/xmlhttprequest.js:676:20)
        at Request.emit (events.js:194:15)
        at Request.onRequestError (/home/noams/dev/web/visual-log-viewer/client/node_modules/request/request.js:881:8)
        at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:189:13)
        at Socket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:392:9)
        at Socket.emit (events.js:189:13)
        at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:82:8)
        at emitErrorAndCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:50:3)
        at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19) undefined
```

Any subsequent file validation tests fail.

I'd appreciate any advice of how to tackle this issue.

Comment: Share code, what you have done so far??

Comment: Thanks TUSHAR, I added code and clarifications.